# Call to external API:s randomly slow after moving integration test to a docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm currently trying to learn docker and as an exercise I moved all our integration tests that we run in azure devops to a docker container. It don't do anything fancy but simply contains the dll:s to my tests. Here are my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1.408-focal

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./Automation .

# run tests on docker run
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "Automation.dll", "--logger", "trx", "--results-directory", "/var/temp", "--filter"]
```

And then I run it in azure devops with a task like this:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: nameOfRegistry
    repository: 'nameOfRepo'
    command: run
    arguments: '--name automation --env TZ=Europe/Stockholm repoUrl:latest "TestCategory=Tickets" --verbosity n'
  continueOnError: true
```

The tests will call REST api:s that we have deployed in azure and it works fine most of the time. But it will randomly get spikes where call that normally take 100-300ms will take 5+ seconds. The problem is that I don't see these issued if I run the tests normally outside docker with a simple `VSTest@2` task (on the same self-hosted agent).

So a test run that may take 20 min with `VSTest@2` will take 30+ min inside docker with `Docker@2`.

So my question is, what could cause this problem? It would be easier to debug if all external api calls where slow but now it seems to happen pretty randomly but enough to make the test run considerably longer.

Comment: To narrow down this issue, does this issue exist if you don't use Azure pipeline?

Comment: I tried to run them locally from visual studio and from the docker container overall it seems to be a bit slower from the container. I see some small spikes but most tests are equal or 0,5-1 sec slower.

Both are slower than docker/VSTest in azure but I guess that's because my internet/computer are worse so nothing strange.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, it seems that there are performance limitation using docker container. I am not familiar with docker container, you could submit this feedback here: https://forums.docker.com/ to contact docker expert to investigate this issue further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the performance issue where because of RestSharper. So I changed to httpclient and now it works a lot faster inside docker.

So if other have similar issue it can be good to check which library you use.